# $A(x) = \prod_{p,q \in \Bbb{P}} (1 - \frac{x^2 - 1}{pq}) = 0$ if and only if $x$ is a twin prime average?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

**Conjecture.**

For any integer $x \geq 1$, we have:
$$
A(x) = \prod_{p,q \in \Bbb{P} \\ p \lt q} \left(1 - \frac{x^2 - 1}{pq}\right) = 0 
$$

if and only if $x$ is a twin prime average.

How can we prove that $A(x)$ either diverges or does not converge to $0$ if $x$ is not a twin prime average?

The $p \lt q$ is not necessary, as $x$ is assumed always an integer; see comments.

I think, but I'm not certain that $A(x)$ can be written:

$$
A(x) = 1 + (x^2 - 1)\lim_{N \to \infty} \ \left(\sum_{n = 4, \ \\ 2\ \mid \ \Omega(n)}^{N} \dfrac{(-1)^{\Omega(n) / 2}}{n}\right)
$$

That is my attempt so far.  I am not sure if it's correct or not.

Comment: Is x a real number?  Does your product over primes p and q assume that p ≠ q ? (If not, then, for every prime p, your product equals 0 at x = √(p^2 + 1).)

Comment: @DanAsimov $x$ is an integer, and yes, I meant $p \lt q$ there! :)  Or we can assume just $x$ is an integer so that $x^2 - p^2 = 1$ has no solution.

Comment: The "if" part is obviously true. If $x$ is the average of twin primes, then by definition $(x-1),(x+1) \in \mathbb P$. Simply naming $x-1=p,x+1=q$ yields $x^2-1=pq$ for some $p,q \in \mathbb P$, whence the product contains a multiplicand equal to $0$, rendering the product $0$. The "only if" part is a little harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core problem with this infinite product is that
$$
\sum_{\substack{p<q\\ \text{prime}}}\frac{1}{pq}
=\frac{1}{2}\left[
 \left(\sum_{p\,\text{prime}}\frac{1}{p}\right)^2
-\sum_{p\,\text{prime}}\frac{1}{p^2}
\right]
= \infty
\tag{1}
$$
as the sum $\sum_{p\,\text{prime}}1/p=\infty$ while
$\sum_{p\,\text{prime}}1/p^2$ converges.

If you plug in $\epsilon=1-x^2$ and take the logarithm to convert the product into a sum,
$$
\ln A(x)
= \sum_{\substack{p<q\\ \text{prime}}}
  \ln\left(1+\frac{\epsilon}{pq}\right)
= \sum_{\substack{p<q\\ \text{prime}}}
  \left(\frac{\epsilon}{pq} + \frac{O(\epsilon^2)}{p^2q^2}\right)
\tag{2}
$$
where the $O(\epsilon^2)$ term is bounded. So the sum diverges to $\pm\infty$ with sign depending on the sign of $\epsilon$.

Thus, if $|x|>1$, then $\epsilon<0$ and the sum becomes $-\infty$ making $A(x)=0$; if $|x|<1$, then $\epsilon>0$ and the sum becomes $+\infty$ making $A(x)=\infty$.

However, if you increase the power in the denominator
$$
F_s(t)
= \prod_{\substack{p<q\\ \text{prime}}}
  \left( 1-\frac{t}{(pq)^s} \right)
$$
it will converge when $s>1$. You can then define $A_s(x)=F_s(-(x^2-1)^s)$ which should have the desired convergence and integer valued roots corresponding to twin-primes.

Comment: Is it known whether $F_s : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ is holomorphic?

Comment: I added tags to two formulas in your post.   Why is the last equality at tag (2) correct?

Comment: @TheGhostOfGaussPossessesMe: You get equation (2) by Taylor expansion of the logarithm. And, yes, $F_s$ will be holomorphic for $s=2,3,\ldots$, and for any $s>1$ provided you select a branch on which to define the non-integer power, eg by excluding negative real $t$.